# nis client unixware stuck on id user

Tags: slackware, nis, unixware

I have configured a NIS server
on Slackware 15
the client is Unixware 7

The client can see the server

```
ypwhich -m passwd
slackware1.mydomain
```

Maps are ok

```
ypcat passwd.byname 
milandra:***:1002:1002::/home/milandra:/bin/bash
```

Id works

```
 id -u milandra 1002
 id -g milandra 1002
```

but..

```
id milandra
```

or

```
id -G milandra
```

stuck and wait

This is the nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         files nis
shadow:         files nis
group:          files nis

hosts:          files dns nis
networks:       files nis

services:       files nis
protocols:      files nis
rpc:            files nis
ethers:         files nis
netmasks:       files nis
netgroup:       files nis
bootparams:     files nis

automount:      files nis
aliases:        files nis
```

What can be the problem?

Using tcpdump show a continuous connection on nis server
in the port used by ypserv.

Enabling debug on ypserv return a lot of lines like those

```
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
ypproc_first_2 from 192.168.201.2 port 34775
    domainname = "mydomain.domain"
    mapname = "group.byname"
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
connect from 192.168.201.2 port 34775 to procedure ypproc_first (mydomain.domain,group.byname;1)
    ypdb_open("mydomain.domain", "group.byname")
Found: mydomain.domain/group.byname (0)
ypdb_close() called
    -> Key = "milandra", Value = "milandra:!:1002:"
```

If i make a /etc/group.nis empty on server then id works
but give this error

```
id  milandra
uid=1002(milandra) gid=1002
UX:id: WARNING: groupid not found in group database
```